# c# Web services php Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services, soap

While we try connect to php Web Service - We face with a known issue, which sounds "Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation"

Solutions in the internet prompt to change our web.config by adding readerQuotas - it does not work.

Below you can find my solution. Could someone advice ? I Would be grateful.
Please also have in mind, that via post method and httpRequest it works well, but such solution is not acceptable.

```
            MIGDZ.Logic_DzSoapServer_QueryIdPortClient client = new Logic_DzSoapServer_QueryIdPortClient();
        MIGDZ.Logic_DzSoapServer_Request_BodyId BodyRequest = new Logic_DzSoapServer_Request_BodyId();
        BodyRequest.nr_dok = "xxxxxx";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxx";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        try
        {
            client.Open();
            var responseArray = client.getParcel(BodyRequest, "xxxxxxxx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
```

Web Config:

```
  <binding name="Logic_DzSoapServer_QueryIdBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
```